# USB 5v temp control for stainless steel wire micro heat elenent

Tags: usb, heat

First, I am new to electronics.
Is it possible to build a usb or battery powered heating element to heat 1ml of water?
How much wire. Needed to hear to 60 deg. c.
I need to control temp and also cycle temp.
Searched but not many examples for this specific scenario for a novice in electrinics.
Any feedback most appreciated.
Cm

Comment: The question is not how hot in the end, but how fast, and how you're going to control the temperature. There's much more to this than just selecting a length of cable. It's really not clear what you're trying to build as an overall device: add a full description of what you're trying to *solve*, maybe with a drawing?

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! Keep in mind that *"Is it possible ...?"* is a yes/no question. In this case, the answer is "Yes". If you're asking us to design it for you, that would be too broad. You would need to specify something about the level of performance you expect as well as what constraints you have on the implementation. What is your specific question?

Answer (score 1):

Heat capacity of water is about 4.2J/gK.

Heating 1ml (1g) of water from 20C to 60C (40K increase) thus requires about 170J of energy.

You can typically get 100mA to 500mA @5V from a common USB 2.0 compliant port.

So at 100mA (0.5J/s) it would take 5 or 6 minutes, ignoring losses. At 500mA it would take a bit over a minute. So maybe it will actually take a couple minutes at 500mA.

Losses are inevitable, and will determine how fast the water cools for your "cycling", so they should be controlled in your design. Maybe you want to assume Newtonian losses at something like 0.01W/K above 20'C, and see how that works out.

This is outside of "electronic" design, however you can use SPICE (eg. LTspice) to simulate thermal systems by using capacitance to represent heat capacity and resistance to represent thermal resistance (time remains time). There are online examples.

Answer (score 0):

It will be as accurate as your temp sensor and may be easier to heat with SMD resistor and SMD sensor using insulated but heat conductive container.